# Showing on-line P = NP

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, proof-techniques, p-vs-np

I have developed a theorem that proposes a method to build algorithms. All the algorithms produced by this method are in P ... they never go up to more than $6(n^{12})$ operations.

Following that, I have defined an algorithm to resolve the TSP-metric. I agree that $6(n^{12})$ is a lot, but it is $P$ and it is the limit of *n* trending to infinite. For $n < 45$ the performance is $5(n^9)$.

> First question: Assuming the theorem is correct, Is this enough to
>   proof $P = NP$ ?

Before publishing the results and the method in a paper, I want to show on-line that the algorithm is in $P$. I can produce an exact result of 45 cities in less than a half of a day since the Held-Karp algorithm will need more than 16 days.

I will certify with a cloud computing provider the host hardware used, but source code will be black-boxed. Inputs will be provided by anyone and she/he/they may be the only one(s) that know(s) the solution.

> Second question: Is this "show" good enough/idea to prove that I actually
>   have solid evidence of it is not a fake?

Important to note that its purpose is only to claim attention showing evidence not substituting the proof of the theorem, I´ll make it publish (public-free) as soon as it will be demanded, I won't keep it in secret. The reason to do this "show" is that being no one if I publish the "theorem" no one gives it a chance. I have checked that way.

Comment: Can you prove that your algorithm runs in polynomial time and always produces an optimal solution?

Comment: By the deterministic time hierarchy theorem there are problems in $P(f(n)^2)$ not in $P(f(n))$. Note that $P(n^{24}) \subset NP$, thus there are problems in NP not solvable in $O(n^12)$. Thus there can exist no method of producing algorithms with complexity $O(n^{12})$ that works for all problems in NP (though this doesn't exclude the possibility of a $O(n^{12})$ algorithm to just TSP).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "resolve the TSP-metric".  What do you mean by "show on-line"?

Comment: @AnttiRöyskö you are right the method (of the theorem) may need for some problems up to $n^{24}$ operations to produce an algorithm, and "n" is a number depending of the kernel of the problem. But when it "optimize" a boolean function it produces an algorithm that throws an exact solution with less than $6(n^{12})$ operations.

Comment: @D.W. I think with ‚on-line’ he means putting a solver on a homepage, such that anybody could use it. On-line as in ‚putting on the internet‘. (He is not referring to an online-algorithm in the ‚usual‘ sense of the class of algorithms that aren‘t fed with the complete onput from the beginning).

Comment: @Ixer Any update?

Comment: @QuoteDave I´m collaborating with a bio-molecular centre to using this method/algorithm against the COVID-19. I´m depicting the protein-protein-docking problem into multidimensional graph but it is not exactly the TSP-metric problem, I have 20 edges (with different distances each-one) between cities. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Ixer Sorry, I am not well versed in biology, though. Though the fact that a biomedicine center is working with you is interesting. Can you give us the name and some proof?

Comment: @QuoteDave Is this important for you? Why?

Comment: @Ixer No, I just think that if a center is actually working with you, then what you may be non-trivial.

Comment: @QuoteDave, of course, ... everything/k I do is not trivial. I´m working in R&D for more than 20 years. I made possible the first Video On Deman streaming engine en 2003, and the first Computing Aided Diagnosing for RECIST and the fist Super Computing Vision System for Radiology. If you can do non-trivial things you must try to do them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Metric TSP is NP-complete - hence *yes*, assuming you can solve the metric TSP in $6(n^{12})$, this is good enough to prove $P=NP$.
2. Giving a blackbox that can do that, would be a quite strong evidence (if it actually works). 
   But there are some considerations one should take into account: it actually could be somewhat dangerous, as someone else could figure out a reduction of crypto-algos to metric-TSP. It could break ‚secure communication‘, blockchain (bitcoin), etc...
   All these technologies are based on the assumption computer scientists and mathematicians have had for decades now, namely that that $P \neq NP$

Comment: thx for your feedback. You are right about its implications, this theorem changes a lot of things. However, to resolve a hash of 512 bits it will need $6(512^10)$ (note that each bit is an independent decision) so even with a lot of supercomputers you will need more than a couple of centuries. Using quantum computers with 512 qbits you can break a hash instantaneously, with a 32 qbit one it will be broken in a few hours.

Comment: @Ixer that is exactly my point: many of the cryptographic tools rely on P != NP. If you manage to solve an NP-Complete problem in poly-time, then this solver can also be used to solve other NP-problems in polytime (like for instance breaking crypto-tools). To do this, you only need to figure out a poly-time reduction of whatever problem you are trying to solve to metric TSP, which might not be trivial but isn‘t that hard either. One basically can ‚translate‘ the crypto-problem into metric TSP, and the än use your blackbox to solve it. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction